# R package: conflict between on.exit function and increasing the number of warnings

Tags: r, package, warnings

One goal of my package is importing molecular datasets and finding inconsistencies in the data. The inconsistencies are reported via warnings. For some datasets, the number of warnings is more than 50 (default value) and it is important that the user sees all the warnings at once. Therefore, I increased the number of displayed warnings via `nwarnings` argument of `options()`.

Additionally, I need to return everything back to normal by using `on.exit()` function, i.e.,

```
oldops <- options(nwarnings = 1000)  
on.exit(options(oldops))
```

I have these two lines consecutively just at the beginning of my function.

However, doing that suppresses all the warnings at once! Without `on.exit()` all the warnings will be displayed.

Is there a reason for this conflict?

I still can change options globally via `.onLoad` function, but I was not sure if I still need to return everything back to normal by using `.onUnload` function. And honestly, I don't know how to do that!! Also, an immediate display of warnings is not an option.

Comment: Can I ask if there is a specific reason you're so tied to using warnings for this?

Comment: Yes, of course. The data is used to derive some inferences, and for having better results, it needs to be cleaned and preprocessed. Any mistake can change the results drastically. So it is important that the inconsistencies (e.g., typos, an unusual type of data different from what the user has pre-specified) are reported. In most of the cases, the import function does not change the entries, it reports them via warnings. In this way, the user can check the data one more time and change it if necessary.

Comment: But is there a particular reason it needs to be warnings instead of say returning a list with all the inconsistencies and having its own print function to display those however you want.

Comment: The main function contains several other integrated functions. Report of inconsistencies needs to be done in a systematic way which seemed more efficient by using the warnings. But you are right, this is one way to do that. I just haven't foreseen this problem and if it remains unresolved I might consider your way. However, I try to avoid that because the package is already documented.